# How do I detect wheter the audio cable is connected?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, alsa

I'm using Ubuntu Lucid (10.04). In my shell script running as root I want to detect whether an audio cable (analog jack) is connected to the laptop or not. How do I do that? I don't need a portable solution, I need something, no matter how hacky, that works on my laptop.

Comment: What makes you think this is possible?

Comment: Cables cannot be detected. Depending on the hardware, a device at the other end of the cable can be detected; in practice, this is only used for headphones detection. Show which HDA codec you have and how it is wired up to the jack.

Comment: @CL: The device at the other end is an externally powered speaker, which is turned on. I don't think it has any smart self-announcement capabilities. How do I figure out which HDA codec I have?

Comment: The hardware can detect it, because it mutes the internal speaker as soon as I connect the external speaker.

Comment: But usually that switch-over is handled by an analog switch which is not instrumented for programatic access. As michas noted, it probably isn't possible.

Comment: Run the [`alsa-info` script](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/AlsaInfo).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One way could perhaps be to use `amixer`.

Jack plugged in:

```
$ amixer -c 0 contents
numid=29,iface=CARD,name='Front Headphone Jack'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=r-------,values=1
  : values=on
...
```

Jack not plugged in:

```
$ amixer -c 0 contents
numid=29,iface=CARD,name='Front Headphone Jack'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=r-------,values=1
  : values=off
...
```

So for that specific one I could do:

```
amixer -c 0 contents | \
awk -F"," '
$1 == "numid=29" {
    c=1
} c && /: values/ {
   split($0, a, "=")
   print a[2];
   exit
}'
```

giving output of `on` or `off`.

---

One can also use commands and specify by `iface` + `name` etc. e.g.:

Get list by:

```
$ amixer -c 0 controls
```

Where `-c 0` specifies card, not needed if default or only one. Then e.g.:

```
$ amixer -c 0 cget numid=29,iface=CARD

$ amixer -c 0 cget numid=29,iface=CARD | awk -F"=" 'NR == 3 {print $2;}'
```

---

I came across a piece of software once, believe it used Tcl/Tk, that displayed pin-power for all ports on the computer + lots of other HW information. It was a nice piece of software – but I can't find it again. I have looked trough 12 old HDD's with no luck. I used it to debug some jack-ports. So yes, it is definitively possible to poll status of a specific port.

Jack is a pain to search the web for due to [JACK](http://jackaudio.org/). It makes it close to impossible.

---

I have some C-code that do some Soundcard information polling. Have to look if I can find it.

Comment: amixer output is subject to change, parsing /proc/asound/card0/codec#0 directly may work better. Alternatively, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25776/detecting-headphone-connection-disconnection-in-linux

Answer (score 0):

Since you said "no matter how hacky" . . .

Get an external sound card that you can connect to your laptop via USB. Plug the analog jack into that. Plug in your external sound card when you want to connect the audio jack and have your bash script detect whether or not the external sound card is connected via USB.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help! I can't use your answer because it detects whether an external sound card is connected, rather than whether the analog jack audio cable is connected.