# Audio (speaker) jack detection with debian

Tags: debian, audio, alsa

How to find out whether speaker jack is connected or not in my motherboard

Tried out some reference from :
   [Detecting headphone connection/disconnection in Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25776/detecting-headphone-connection-disconnection-in-linux)

pasted my amixer output.Need guidance on detecting the audio jack plug in and plug out.

```
    numid=1,iface=MIXER,name='Mic Capture Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=on
numid=2,iface=MIXER,name='Mic Capture Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=1,min=0,max=6144,step=0
  : values=0
  | dBminmax-min=6.00dB,max=30.00dB
debian:/opt/vortex/bin# amixer -c0 contents
numid=36,iface=MIXER,name='Master Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=on
numid=35,iface=MIXER,name='Master Playback Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=1,min=0,max=31,step=0
  : values=31
  | dBscale-min=-46.50dB,step=1.50dB,mute=0
numid=11,iface=MIXER,name='Headphone Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=2
  : values=on,on
numid=37,iface=MIXER,name='PCM Playback Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---RW-,values=2,min=0,max=255,step=0
  : values=255,255
  | dBscale-min=-51.00dB,step=0.20dB,mute=0
numid=19,iface=MIXER,name='Front Mic Boost'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=3,step=0
  : values=0,0
  | dBscale-min=0.00dB,step=10.00dB,mute=0
numid=15,iface=MIXER,name='Front Mic Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=2
  : values=off,off
numid=14,iface=MIXER,name='Front Mic Playback Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=31,step=0
  : values=0,0
  | dBscale-min=-34.50dB,step=1.50dB,mute=0
numid=2,iface=MIXER,name='Front Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=2
  : values=on,on
numid=1,iface=MIXER,name='Front Playback Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=31,step=0
  : values=31,31
  | dBscale-min=-46.50dB,step=1.50dB,mute=0
numid=4,iface=MIXER,name='Surround Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=2
  : values=on,on
numid=3,iface=MIXER,name='Surround Playback Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=31,step=0
  : values=0,0
  | dBscale-min=-46.50dB,step=1.50dB,mute=0
numid=7,iface=MIXER,name='Center Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=on
numid=5,iface=MIXER,name='Center Playback Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=1,min=0,max=31,step=0
  : values=0
  | dBscale-min=-46.50dB,step=1.50dB,mute=0
numid=8,iface=MIXER,name='LFE Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=on
numid=6,iface=MIXER,name='LFE Playback Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=1,min=0,max=31,step=0
  : values=0
  | dBscale-min=-46.50dB,step=1.50dB,mute=0
numid=17,iface=MIXER,name='Line Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=2
  : values=off,off
numid=16,iface=MIXER,name='Line Playback Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=31,step=0
  : values=0,0
  | dBscale-min=-34.50dB,step=1.50dB,mute=0
numid=18,iface=MIXER,name='Mic Boost'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=3,step=0
  : values=0,0
  | dBscale-min=0.00dB,step=10.00dB,mute=0
numid=13,iface=MIXER,name='Mic Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=2
  : values=off,off
numid=12,iface=MIXER,name='Mic Playback Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=31,step=0
  : values=0,0
  | dBscale-min=-34.50dB,step=1.50dB,mute=0
numid=20,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=2
  : values=on,on
numid=21,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Switch',index=1
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=2
  : values=on,on
numid=22,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=31,step=0
  : values=0,0
  | dBscale-min=-16.50dB,step=1.50dB,mute=0
numid=23,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Volume',index=1
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=31,step=0
  : values=0,0
  | dBscale-min=-16.50dB,step=1.50dB,mute=0
numid=30,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Default PCM Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=on
numid=26,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Con Mask'
  ; type=IEC958,access=r-------,values=1
  : values=[AES0=0x0f AES1=0xff AES2=0x00 AES3=0x00]
numid=27,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Pro Mask'
  ; type=IEC958,access=r-------,values=1
  : values=[AES0=0x0f AES1=0x00 AES2=0x00 AES3=0x00]
numid=28,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Default'
  ; type=IEC958,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=[AES0=0x04 AES1=0x00 AES2=0x00 AES3=0x00]
numid=29,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=off
numid=32,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Capture Default'
  ; type=IEC958,access=r-------,values=1
  : values=[AES0=0x04 AES1=0x00 AES2=0x00 AES3=0x00]
numid=31,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Capture Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=off
numid=34,iface=MIXER,name='Beep Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=2
  : values=off,off
numid=33,iface=MIXER,name='Beep Playback Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=31,step=0
  : values=0,0
  | dBscale-min=-34.50dB,step=1.50dB,mute=0
numid=24,iface=MIXER,name='Input Source'
  ; type=ENUMERATED,access=rw------,values=1,items=3
  ; Item #0 'Mic'
  ; Item #1 'Front Mic'
  ; Item #2 'Line'
  : values=0
numid=25,iface=MIXER,name='Input Source',index=1
  ; type=ENUMERATED,access=rw------,values=1,items=3
  ; Item #0 'Mic'
  ; Item #1 'Front Mic'
  ; Item #2 'Line'
  : values=0
numid=10,iface=MIXER,name='Side Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=2
  : values=on,on
numid=9,iface=MIXER,name='Side Playback Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=31,step=0
  : values=0,0
  | dBscale-min=-46.50dB,step=1.50dB,mute=0
```

Comment: Just compare the output with the phones plugged in and amixer output with them unplugged, that should give enough hints.

Comment: @Anthon : i dont see any changes in diff

Comment: Maybe your hardware is connected in a different way than mine was. I assume the phones work (and it is not something like a frontpanel not hooked up to the motherboard)?

Comment: @Anthon : AM plugging my phones jack in motherboard's back panel(green jack slot). Also is there any other recommendations.

Comment: I am trying to find the program that I used to use that changed the output from my USB speakers to my analogue headphones on plug-in, when I have that I will get back. Might not be until this WE.

Comment: @Anthon Any luck???

Comment: Of course I could not find it and forgot about it. But I looked some more this morning and found the problem was that I looked for amixer. What I did is that I compared `/proc/asound/card0/codec#0` with and without headphones. There are multiple lines starting with ` Pin-ctls` that change in that "file" when I plug-in my head-phones.

Comment: @Anthon : I trird the same technique but I dont c any changes ...